# How to remove bathtub drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

This bathtub drain gets stuck whenever I try to pull it out. Is there a different removal method to get it out besides turning the drain anti-clockwise?
[image]

Comment: why would you keep trying to pull it through the hole? ... it looks too large to pass through

Comment: Looks like the part that removes from above is already removed. If you want to remove the "drain shoe" (part below/outside the tub) you either need to come in from below or take the tub out. I honestly can't even imagine what you think you are accomplishing in this picture....?

Comment: [Unable to remove push-pull stopper from tub drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/190002/unable-to-remove-push-pull-stopper-from-tub-drain) ? Picture w/o the tool in it? Is that actually drain pipe, or what's left of a stopper? - "You would pull hard up on the assembly and twist counter-clockwise, Pulling the assembly up with force, while twisting counter-clockwise, might apply enough fiction to grip the retaining nut below. The issues then become **can you access the area beneath to lock the assembly back in place**."

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a traditional tub drain. Usually they unscrew and can be lifted out of the hole so that they can be replaced.

[Related article](https://www.instructables.com/Replacing-Bath-Tub-Drain/)

I am not sure how common this style of drain is, but to fix you need to cut out the drain from below.

Comment: This should probably be edited into the original question or a comment instead of as an answer.